# Edit boot menu from Ubuntu on a laptop with Win 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have a problem that is giving me a headache for months and I hope that in this, my first question here, you can help me out.

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop with a default win 8 system. I has taken a while but I have managed. The only resulting problem was that when I start my computer I can only access a boot menu where Ubunty appears if I press F9.

In order to get a decent boot menu I have learnt that Win 8 is messing around very badly and being evil as Microsoft does so well. I have tried to go through this jungle of unknown terms for me (UEFI, Grub, etc.) and the difficulties that Win 8 creates when I found a little piece of software for Win 8 that apparently would solve my problems allowing to edit the boot menu so I get what I have. It's called EasyBCD 2.2.0.182.

I'm sure it's a good programme when used by wise hands. However, I managed to create a menu with a few options where none of them would be valid! I could only access Ubuntu through the esc key but I can't access windows anymore.

So, is there a way I can edit the boot menu from Ubuntu? Maybe using the Win software I mentioned from Ubuntu (I believe this can be done) to undo the problematic menu I created?

Thanks!!!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

The last I heard (which was a while ago), EasyBCD was pretty useless on EFI-based computers. Unless you can find EFI-specific instructions, I'd stop messing with it, since you aren't likely to get very far and could actually make matters worse.

Instead, I recommend you check out [EasyUEFI,](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) which provides a point-and-click interface to the EFI boot manager. You should be able to use this to set the `ubuntu` entry first, which will in turn launch GRUB, which should enable you to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. (If GRUB has no Windows entry, then that's another problem.)

In some cases, computers "forget" or ignore their EFI boot entries. The fact that you're having the problem that you're reporting suggests that this may be the case for you. If so, the best solution is to return the computer for a refund and get another one, since computers with this problem are defective. There are ugly workarounds, but until people start telling manufacturers that they won't accept defective merchandise, manufacturers will continue to deliver it. You'll need to try a few things (like EasyUEFI) before you can be certain you're in this boat, though.